# Buttons do not open link unless I click the web icon

Tags: html, css

The buttons I created to link to my social media are not working as expected. When I click the button it doesn't open the link unless I click the link's icon.

[image: Screenshot of Contact Us header and four social media icons.]

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<section id="contact" class="py-5 text-center">
  <div class="container text-center ml-auto">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="info-header md-5 text-light ">
          <h1 class="text-primary pb-3">CONTACT US</h1>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success mr-3">
              <a style="color: green;" target="_blank" href="https://wa.me/2349080237740"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp fa-1x"></i></a>
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-3">
              <a class="text-primary" target="_blank" href="https://t.me/dopewilly"><i class="fa fa-telegram fa-1x"></i></a>
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-danger mr-3">
              <a class="text-danger" target="_blank" href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-1x"></i></a>
          </button>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-info">
              <a target="_blank" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-1x"></i></a>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: hi. put your code is here, pls

Comment: @s.kuznetsov here is the code below. Though you need bootstrap to run it.

Comment: Your HTML  is invalid.  [You can not have an `a` tag as a child of a `button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button). Just style the `a` tag like a button instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the `<a>` inside the `<button>` which is invalid and creates the issue you are encountering, move your `<button>` classes to the `<a>` and remove the `<button>` tags after, like this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<section id="contact" class="py-5 text-center">
  <div class="container text-center ml-auto">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="info-header md-5 text-light ">
          <h1 class="text-primary pb-3">CONTACT US</h1>
              <a class="btn btn-outline-success mr-3" style="color: green;" target="_blank" href="https://wa.me/2349080237740"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp fa-1x"></i></a>
              <a class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-3 text-primary" target="_blank" href="https://t.me/dopewilly"><i class="fa fa-telegram fa-1x"></i></a>
              <a class="btn btn-outline-danger mr-3 text-danger" target="_blank" href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-1x"></i></a>
              <a class="btn btn-outline-info" target="_blank" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-1x"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```